# AHK using three or more key presses to trigger hotkey/hotstring

Tags: autohotkey

I know this question has been discussed before (several years ago). I am hoping there is a new way to achieve this goal. I would simply like to use three or more keys to trigger an AHK script. For example, CTRL + SHIFT + Q to do a thing

In "fake" ahk, this would be

^+Q::
...
return

Of course, this type of command errors. The previous solution is quite verbose compared to the task and involves checking the state of some key etc. Is there a shorthand way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

Please describe the error you get.  The example you give does not produce an error for me.

But for one thing, a shift modifier on "Q" has no add'l effect (a Shift on "q" gives "Q").

But in the meantime, AHK is quite forgiving and any of these work:

```
^+Q::
    msgbox %A_ThisHotkey%
return

^Q::
    msgbox %A_ThisHotkey%
return

^+q::
    msgbox %A_ThisHotkey%
return
```

And in general two or even three modifier keys (Ctrl+Alt+Shift) is quite normal in practice.  if you want two or more non-modifier keys, you will have to track key state.  I guess you know that from your reference to what was "discussed before (several years ago)."

Comment: You are 100% correct and I am 100% dumb dumb. This question should be deleted but I will not be the decider of that, as it might benefit someone who makes a similar mistake. Instead of writing 

^+q:: 
do a thing
Return

I had written 

::^+q::
do a thing
Return

I've been using ahk for about four days now and didn't realize the difference was critical. I even typed it correctly in my question...

Comment: Glad it worked out. Doing hotstrings shows an interesting result of the hotkey internal variable.  `::PQ::msgbox %A_ThisHotkey%`  But there are also ways to enforce strict capitalizations, so you are well equipped. Mark this answeref pls & thx